# Combining two regex expressions - with lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: regex

I was tasked with creating a regex to match the last two characters in a name given a specific string (input):

> `1732 - George Washinton Junior - US president - 1799`

the regex should match the following:

> `ge, on, or`

I managed to create a regex to only match the name:

> `(?<=\d - ).*(?=- \D)`

which returns:

> `George Washinton Junior`  //note the space at the end of string

I apply a second regex on this:

> `\w{2}(?= )`

which matches the desired values: `ge, on, or`. I was challenged to come up with a regex that combines both of them together to achieve the same results (on the original input). Since I'm a newbie in regex I have no idea how this could be achieved. I would really appreciate some feedback as to how I should/could approach this task :)

Comment: What programming language or tool is the ReGex written for?

Comment: So essentially you are looking for something along the lines of `\w+ge \w+on \w+or\b`, making sure that the three words are ending on 'ge', 'on' and 'or' in sequence?

Comment: I'm using ECMAScript (testing on regex101.com)

Comment: ECMAScript has various implementations. Which one will you use? JavaScript as used in current Chrome and FireFox? Or C++/VBA ECMAScript 262?

Comment: @JvdV Sorry, should've made myself clearer: the regex should only match the last two characters in each part of the name, but only in the name (not the string following the second "-")

Comment: So did you meant something like: [`(?=.*-.*-)[a-z]{2}(?=\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/XLTrnb/2)?

Answer (score 1):

i think `(?<=\d+ - [\w\s]*?)\w{2}(?= )` will work for you as combination

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5l8mn7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/(?<=^[^-]*\s-\s[^-]*)\S{2}(?!\S)/g
/(?<=^\d+\s+-\s[^-]*)\S{2}(?!\S)/g
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/8hU1Or/2) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/8hU1Or/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=^[^-]*\s-\s[^-]*)` - a positive lookbehind matching a location immediately preceded with

  - `^` - start of string
  - `[^-]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `-`
  - `\s-\s` - a `-` enclosed with whitespace chars
  - `[^-]*` - any 0 or more chars other than `-`
- `\S{2}` - any two non-whitespace chars
- `(?!\S)` - a whitespace or end of string is required immediately to the right of the current location.

If you need to make sure the two chars are letters, use

```
/(?<=^[^-]*\s-\s[^-]*)\p{L}{2}(?!\S)/gu
```

(Note this regex cannot be tested at regex101.com since it does not support Unicode property classes, though JavaScript `RegExp` in current Chrome, Firefox and Node.js and some other ennvironments already support them).

JS demo:

```js
const text = "1732 - George Washinton Junior - US president - 1799";
console.log(text.match(/(?<=^[^-]*\s-\s[^-]*)\p{L}{2}(?!\S)/gu));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to go back, better to go forward.
Its faster and it's compatible with all browsers.

`[a-z]{2}(?=\s(?:[^-]*-){2}\s*\d+\s*$)`

see https://regex101.com/r/XLTrnb/1

Comment: I did not downvote. But if you state "Its faster" then better support that with explanation why. And if you state "it's compatible with all browsers" then you should also explain why, or maybe what alternative is not; especially to avoid the impression of implying that all the other answers have a shortcoming. Or to explain how they do. I could imagine that someboy downvoted for disliling the impression that you wrote "My answer is better than the others." without backup.

Comment: And here is some reason on why votes (up and down) are intentionally anonymous. https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: @Yunnosch Fair points all. But faster, better, more efficient, and please accept because of it is a selling point that I can back up but if you don't know that then I can give you private lessons, but its not appropriate here is it ? I'm addressing the beginner, not someone like yourself.

Comment: Ps, I don't think you personally downvoted me @Yunnosch  so you don't have to _qualify_ your comments. Also, if you look at my reputation, you'll see a serial downvoter is on my tail, nothing personal, but if I didn't know so much about regex I would think my expertise isn't what I thought it was.

Comment: "But faster, better, more efficient", please back that up by explanation. "please accept because of it is a selling point" No. I decline to accept those unsupported statements, *because* they are a selling point. Rather them being a selling point increases the need to back them up by explanation. Private lessons are not the idea of StackOverflow,but providing insightful explanation to everybody is. I prefer to clarify that I did not downvote if I comment in a way which otherwise could be miunderstood at me reasoning why I downvoted, i.e. in immediate context of a comment like yours.

Comment: The grammar of "but if I didn't know so much about regex I would think my expertise isn't what I thought it was." is slightly beyond my non-native English skills. But to me it seems that it could be read as "I have lots of expertise. I can tell, because I think it is great and would not think so if it weren't great." Which I think cannot be what you wanted to express. So I am confused. But even if you could convincingly claim great regex expertise, it still does not help with understanding your regex and how it is faster and with learning from your expertise. For that you'd have to explain.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sorry for the confusion. Because someone says they provide a _faster_ thereby more efficent way of doing a common specific task, it's usually understood as so or challenged as not so. I don't think you request proof of every answer that presents itself as having performant attributes do you ?  You think I am saying I am an expert and I'm sorry you would take offense to that.

Comment: @Yunnosch Assertions are atomic, done in order, can't be backtracked into, can't be optimized out. To put one before a literal is slower by at least a factor of 2.
Here, these 2 examples are identical and made complex to mitigate compiler optimization: _after better_  https://regex101.com/r/mosoJH/1, _before worse_ https://regex101.com/r/X35hrZ/1.

Comment: con't @Yunnosch By injecting an atomic assertion operation before a literal induces execution at every character position before it checks for the literal itself.
This is an extra step, and by step it is meant a wasted state / function call. Again, this is common knowlege, a basic tenent of Regular Expressions.

Comment: con't @Yunnosch As you may know, traditional C api string comparison is done left to right. Since regex is nothing but string comparison, the idea of a lookbehind induces heavy pointer arithmetic. 
By allowing algo for a variable width lookbehind you have to make some very heavy heuristic moves compounding the inherent latency. 
All common knowlege. Was there any other technical questions you had ?

Comment: Now that seems like the real stuff. Thank you. Would you like to move those interesting explanations into the answer itself?